# AWS SageMaker Cloud Formation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

I'm in middle of writing a CF template on AWS SageMaker, I've added the resources of Instance Notebooks, Endpoints, Endpoint configuration, Models...

Do I need to add any other resources to complete the template or these alone are enough to create the stack and provision this service in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the resource you need then for sure you can just deploy this as a single CloudFormation stack.

If you ever need to add more resources in the future (Lambda Functions, Api Gateway etc .), you could always simply edit your template file and redeploy it to AWS CF

Comment: Thanks Velociraptor11, my question is about the simple AWS SageMaker service, I haven't worked on it earlier, need to write this CFT of ML... If the above 4 resources are good enough, then I could process further...